# Caesar cipher fails when output character is beyond 'z'

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x, encryption

Just to be clear, I am asking this because I have tried it for about 1.5 hours and can't seem to get any results. I am not taking a programming class or anything but I have a lot of free time this summer and I am using a lot of it to learn python from this book. I want to know how I would complete this problem.

The problem asks for you to create a program which runs a "caesar cipher" which shifts the ascii number of a character down by a certain key that you choose.  For instance, if I wanted to write sourpuss and chose a key of 2, the program would spit out the ascii characters all shifted down by two. So s would turn into u, o would turn into q (2 characters down the ascii alphabet...).

I could get that part by writing this program.

```
def main():
    the_word=input("What word would you like to encode? ")
    key=eval(input("What is the key? "))
    message=""
    newlist=str.split(the_word)
    the_word1=str.join("",the_word)
    for each_letter in the_word1:
        addition=ord(each_letter)+key
        message=message+chr(addition)
    print(message)
main()
```

Running this program, you get the following:

```
What word would you like to encode? sourpuss
What is the key? 2
uqwtrwuu
```

Now, the next question says that an issue arises if you add the key to the ascii number and that results in a number higher than 128. It asks you to create a program that implements
a system where if the number is higher than 128, the alphabet would reset and you would go back to an ascii value of 0.

What I tried to do was something like this:

```
if addition>128:
    addition=addition-128
```

When I ran the program after doing this, it didn't work and just returned a space instead of the right character.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using modular arithmetic instead of a condition:

```
((ord('z') + 0 - 97) % 26) + 97
=> 122 # chr(122) == 'z'

((ord('z') + 1 - 97) % 26) + 97
=> 97 # chr(97) == 'a'

((ord('z') + 2 - 97) % 26) + 97
=> 98 # chr(98) == 'b'
```

Notice that this expression:

```
((ord(character) + i - 97) % 26) + 97
```

Returns the correct integer representing the given `character` *after* we add an offset `i` (the *key*, as you call it). In particular, if we add `0` to `ord('z')` then we get back the code for `'z'`. If we add `1` to `ord('z')` then we get the code for `a`, and so on.

This works for lowercase characters between `a-z`, with the magic numbers `97` being the code for `a` and `26` being the number of characters between `a` and `z`; tweaking those numbers you can adapt the code for supporting a greater range of characters.

Comment: excellent...i wish i could've thought of that. works great now.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't 128 characters in the English alphabet, so you shouldn't subtract with 128. And I don't know why you think the problem would be at 128. The ordinal of the last character of the English alphabet is 122. Reasonably the problem happens when you reach 122.

Also, you aren't taking care of uppercase vs lowercase, but that's OK, I guess, as long as you always use lowercase. :-)

You mentioned doing it for "more characters". What you can do is do a binary Caesar cipher, that doesn't care about what characters you are using, but just looks at it as numbers.

```
def cipher(text, key):
    return [(c + key) % 256 for c in text.encode('utf8')]

def decipher(data, key):
    return bytes([(c - key) % 256 for c in data]).decode('utf8')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = cipher("This is a test text. !^äöp%&ł$€", 101)
    print("Cipher data:", data)
    print("Text:", decipher(data, 101))
```

Output:

```
Cipher data: [185, 205, 206, 216, 133, 206, 216, 133, 198, 133, 217, 202, 216, 217, 133, 217, 202, 221, 217, 147, 133, 134, 195, 40, 9, 40, 27, 213, 138, 139, 42, 231, 137, 71, 231, 17]
Text: This is a test text. !^äöp%&ł$€
```

Comment: yeah i was thinking about doing it for all characters not just letters....Also it works for uppercase as well.

Comment: @Pcarlitz: The question then is what "all characters" are. You are talking Python 3 here, which has Unicode strings. Unicode has 110.000 characters, and their values are not in one sequence. And not all characters are even allowed at any place. So this then becomes a complete nightmare. But you can do it with binary data, but then the problem doesn't appear at >128 but >255.

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating this into your code. What this will do is that if your caesar cipher's ascii number goes above the value of the ascii value of z then it will - 26. For example if the value of your addition variable goes to 123, the program will minus 26 to give you 97 to give you 'a'. This also works if the ascii value goes below the value of 'a'.

```
if addition > ord("z")
    addition -= 26
elif addition < ord("a"):
    addition+=26
```